# In Javascript, how do you select "option" attribute from "select" element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript, how would I get whatever option the user selects from the menu list? I'm trying to make it so that when the first option "default" is selected, it displays an error message.

How do i do this in Javascript without changing the HTML? Thanks in advance!

```html
<div class="error"></div>
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="menu">Menu List</label>
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option value="default">Choose an image...</option>
      <option value="fries">Fries</option>
      <option value="ice-cream">Ice cream</option>
      <option value="cake">Cheesecake</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("menu").value`

Comment: or https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_selected.asp

Comment: Also, I don't know why you would need to do this. It would be much better to just make the `default` option `disabled`.

Comment: The selected _options_ are always [`yourSelectElement.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions). Then you can choose what you need: their `value`? Their `textContent`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon That's normally only used for a multi-select.

Comment: You can also give it an empty value and add the `required` attribute to the `select`. The browser will then automatically refuse to submit the form unless they select one of the other options.

Comment: @Barmar The question should specify what exactly they’re trying to get. `.value` is the `value` property of the currently selected `<option>`, but `.selectedOptions` includes the currently selected `<option>`s.

Comment: he just wants to check if the `default` option is selected. `if (document.getElementById("menu").value  == 'default')` @SebastianSimon

Comment: @SebastianSimon Why would you suggest anything more complicated than that?

Comment: I find it very rude to delete a question someone is trying to help you with. Please undelete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66928646/295783) and we can take it from there. If you notice I have given you a complete solution

Answer (score 1):

Get the `value` property of the `<select>` element.

```js
document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let choice = document.getElementById("menu").value;
  if (choice == "default") {
    alert("Please select an image");
  } else {
    console.log("Thank you for purchasing " + choice);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="error"></div>
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="menu">Menu List</label>
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option value="default">Choose an image...</option>
      <option value="fries">Fries</option>
      <option value="ice-cream">Ice cream</option>
      <option value="cake">Cheesecake</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to use the form submit event instead of a submit button's click event - and you need preventDefault in both cases

Answer (score 0):

If select has a blank first value and the select is required, they cannot submit the form

```js
const sel = document.getElementById("menu");
sel.options[0].value=""; // remove the value
sel.setAttribute("required","required");
```

```html
<div class="error"></div>
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="menu">Menu List</label>
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option value="default">Choose an image...</option>
      <option value="fries">Fries</option>
      <option value="ice-cream">Ice cream</option>
      <option value="cake">Cheesecake</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```